# Odoo 13 can't connect to PostgreSQL 10.5

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-13

I have installed odoo 13 on EC2 Ubuntu server and i have a separate RDS PostgreSQL instance that i have created. Odoo starts, but when i access it i get this error.

```
ERROR odoo13 odoo.sql_db: bad query: SELECT
ERROR: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT latest_version FROM ir_module_module WHERE name='base...
```

I tried to use `dbfilter = odoo13` as some have suggested in different posts.
Similar things have been asked here and github but noone is providing a correct solution.
Any help?

Comment: Do you have everything configured correctly? Like db user/role, its access rights in db, connections settings in Odoo configuration (file), and so on? Seems to me the database was created empty, which could be if Odoo's db user has not enough rights to create tables for example.

Comment: I am using master username/master password, here is my config
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/51400

Comment: The database is empty as created by RDS, Odoo should create it. This issue does not exist with Odoo11. A workaround would be https://superuser.com/questions/1405011/odoo12-err-on-setting-remote-database-to-be-at-amazon-rds/1407488, but is it possible to do it without that?